# Where to see logs when meteor crash without any message while developing? (on Windows)

Tags: meteor

While developing, my Meteor App is often crashing **without printing any message** like that :

[image]

The last line of the screenshot is corresponding to the current project directory where i can type the `meteor` command, meaning meteor crashed.

It forces me to restart meteor with the `meteor` command.

Where can i see logs to understand why my meteor crashed ?

Answer (score 1):

That's ongoing problem with Meteor, sometimes it crashes without any logs after code reload. See this issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8648

Comment: Thanks, i will look at it